# WSS support for C# .exe to work over https

Tags: c#, https, wss

I have .net .exe, which listens to web sockets. It works perfectly over http.
When my sender shifted to WSS over https, my .exe is unable to decrypt the incoming request.
My client receives byte array, but when I try to decrypt it to UTF Encoding, it doesn't decrypt correctly via `Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1");`

Code:

```cs
public void ReadCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    try
    {
        // Retrieve the state object
        // and the handler socket
        // from the asynchronous state object.
        var state = (StateObject)ar.AsyncState;
        // Read data from the client socket. 
        var bytesRead = _socket.EndReceive(ar);

        // Below code doesn't decrypt correctly for wss
        // but works correctly for ws
        Utils.Encoding.GetString(state.Buffer, 0, bytesRead);
```

Comment: What web-socket API are you using? does it know that it is using TLS? etc - without some code, this is hard to comment on, but to generalize: "yes, that should probably work, if configured correctly"

Comment: `
public void ReadCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            try
            {
                // Retrieve the state object
                // and the handler socket
                // from the asynchronous state object.
                var state = (StateObject)ar.AsyncState;
                // Read data from the client socket. 
                var bytesRead = _socket.EndReceive(ar);
`

** Below code doesn't decrypt correctly for was, 
but works correctly for ws**
`
Utils.Encoding.GetString(state.Buffer, 0, bytesRead) 
`

Comment: Encoding.GetsString doesnt decrypt my stream , this the problem.

Comment: `Encoding` *never* deals with decryption - that isn't the job of an `Encoding` - but: the code in your comment really helps here; I've edited it into the question, because it is so important

Answer (score 1):

In your existing code, you're talking raw bytes at the socket layer, going direct from the `Socket` to an `Encoding`. This is fine for unencrypted data, because the data *literally is* the same bytes (although ... only the first part of the handshake is text; after the HTTP headers, you should be dealing with frame parsers, ideally, so going near an `Encoding` here is a bit dangerous; context: I too have written a successful, high throughput, web-socket server direct from the `Socket` layer).

But: it isn't that simple when you have any byte translations to do in the middle - with TLS being the case here (you'd have the same issues if this was a compression translation, too).

Quite simply: someone needs to handle the actual TLS work. If you are determined to handle the details yourself, then your best bet here is probably to wrap:

`Socket` <===> `NetworkStream` <===> `SslStream` <===> (your code)

which means you'd be coding against the `Stream` API, not the `Socket` API (presumably using `AuthenticateAsServer()` when initializing the server stream). To avoid having two code-bases, you can use just:

`Socket` <===> `NetworkStream` <===> (your code)

for the `ws` layer. However, frankly IMO it would be better to let the framework and libraries worry about this - especially if you are on .NET Core: you can use Kestrel to set up a web-server with TLS support, with your code essentially being just:

```cs
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    app.UseWebSockets(new WebSocketOptions()
    {
        // set KeepAliveInterval / ReceiveBufferSize / etc
    });
    app.Run(ctx =>
    {
        if (ctx.WebSockets.IsWebSocketRequest)
        {
            return RunClientAsync(ctx);
        }
        else { /* whatever you want to do when not WS/WSS */ }
    });
}
private async Task RunClientAsync(HttpContext context)
{
    var socket = await context.WebSockets.AcceptWebSocketAsync();
    // TODO: all your read/write logic using the WebSocket API
}
```

This approach scales much better on .NET Core 3.1 than it did on .NET Framework (checks my status page); I'm currently running ~518,000 concurrent web-socket connections on 9 nodes (because I just happened to have 9 nodes available), at virtually 0% CPU, 5 ports per node (to avoid ephemeral port exhaustion) ~11,500 connections per port per node. We migrated our custom `Socket`-level code to use the `WebSocket` API with .NET Core 3.1, because the improvements meant that it *no longer made sense* for us to maintain our own code dealing with the nuances of web-socket protocol(s).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, problem I have now is, I have legacy server(console .exe) which is on .net framework and not on .net core. I cant migrate it to .net core currently.
What I am looking for is like, when I receive request over 'ws', then it decrypts correctly and then I add handshake to it, but my client tries to connect it through 'wss', it can not decrypt that and hence I cant create handshake with my client. The client is deployed on ISS where certificate is installed. I have installed same certificate on server (.exe) with private key but no luck with my existing code.

Comment: @TusharMali if you're talking directly to a `Socket`: you probably aren't hosting in IIS; sure, IIS might be on the same box and have the cert, but I don't think it is involved in this custom server, so: it is irrelevant. In your scenario, I wonder whether the more pragmatic option is to use a load-balancer/reverse-proxy as a gateway, and *terminate the TLS at the load balancer*: so from the external client's perspective, they're talking TLS, but the traffic from the load balancer to your service: is not encrypted. I've used haproxy to do this in the past

Comment: Yes, proxy is one of the solution.